# Why are my threads I created not printed in order?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, race-condition

I have this program:

```
void *func(void *arg) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    int *id = (int *)arg;

    printf("My ID is %d\n" , *id);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

int main() {
    int i;
    pthread_t tid[3];

    // Let us create three threads
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, func, (void *)&i);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

I expected it to output this:

```
My ID is 0
My ID is 1
My ID is 2
```

But instead I get random output, such as this:

```
My ID is 0
My ID is 0
My ID is 2
```

Since I already added mutex lock, I thought it would solve the problem. What else did I do wrong? Is this related to race condition?

Answer (score 4):

Here `id` points to the same variable `i` in main for all the threads.

```
int *id = (int *)arg;

printf("My ID is %d\n" , *id);
```

But the variable `i` is constantly being update by the two `for`-loops in `main` behind the threads back. So before the thread reaches the point of `printf`, the value of `i`, and therefore also the value of `*id`, may have changed.

There are a few ways to solve this. The best way depends on the use case:

1. Wait in `main` until the thread signals that it has made a copy of `*id` before modifying `i` or letting it go out of scope.
2. Declare and initialize an array, `int thread_id[]`, and create the threads like this:
   `pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, func, &thread_id[i]);`
3. `malloc` some memory and and initialize it with a copy of `i`:

   ```
   int *thread_id = malloc(sizeof(*thread_id));
   *thread_id = i
   pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, func, thread_id);
   ```

   Just don't forget to `free` your memory int the thread when you are finished using it. Or in `main` if the thread fails to start.
4. If `i` fits in a `void *` can pass its content directly as a parameter to the thread. To make sure it fits, you can declare it as `intptr_t` rather than `int`
   (We basicly abuse the fact that pointers are nothing more than *magic* integers) :

   ```
   void *func(void *arg) {
       pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
       // Here we interpret a pointer value as an integer value
       intptr_t id = (intptr_t )arg;

       printf("My ID is %d\n" , (int)id);
       pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
   }

   int main() {
       intptr_t i;
       pthread_t tid[3];

       // Let us create three threads
       for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
           // Here we squeeze the integer value of `i` into something that is
           // supposed to hold a pointer
           pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, func, (void *)i);
       }

       for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
           pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);
       }

       // This does not belong here !!
       // pthread_exit(NULL);
       return 0;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

<del>Nope, no race conditions involved.</del> (my b) There can be a race condition on i because all threads access it. Each thread gets started with a pointer to i. However, the main problem is that there is no guarantee that the thread will start and run the critical section while i holds the value you expect, in an order that you expect.

I'm assuming you declared the variable `mutex` globally and called `pthread_mutex_init()` somewhere to initialize it.

Mutexes are great to allow *only one thread* to access a critical section of code at a time. So the code as you've written creates all three threads to run in parallel, but only lets *one thread at a time* run the following code.

```
int *id = (int *)arg;

printf("My ID is %d\n" , *id);
```

Comment: There is, in fact, a race condition:  `main()`'s local variable `i` is incremented (by the for-loops in `main()`) without first locking the mutex.  The threads read the current value of `i` while holding the mutex locked, but in order to avoid race conditions, *all reads and writes* of the shared variable must be serialized -- serializing only the reads is not sufficient.